# Derivatives of inverses

Tags: derivatives, inverse-function

So I know that if $f(3)=4$, $f^{-1}(4)=3$ for all $x,y$ where the functions are defined.. but does the same rule apply to derivatives? i.e. if $f'(3)=4$, does $(f^{-1})'(4)=3$ ?

Comment: What does hold is, if for example $f(3)=4$, then $(f^{-1})'(4) = \frac{1}{f'(3)}$.

Comment: The comment of @Cornman can also be (very informally) inferred geometrically.  $f'(x)$ = $\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}$.  Now rotate the *graph* of $y = f(x)$ counter-clockwise by $(90^{\circ})$, so that you are looking at the *graph* of $x = f^{-1}(y)$.  Consider that $\frac{df^{-1}(y)}{dy} = \frac{\Delta x}{\Delta y}.$

Comment: No.  But $f(f^{-1}(x))= x$ so by the chain rule we know $f'(f^{-1}(x)) f^{-1}(x) = 1$ so $f'(x) = \frac 1{f'(f^{-1}(x))}$

Answer (score 3):

No. Take
$$f:\mathbb{R}_+\to\mathbb{R}_+~~~~~~~f:x\mapsto x^2$$
Its inverse is
$$f^{-1}(x)=\sqrt{x}$$
Observe that
$$f'(x)=2x$$
So
$$f'(3)=6$$
But
$$(f^{-1})'(x)=\frac{1}{2\sqrt x}$$
Thus
$$(f^{-1})'(6)=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{6}}\neq 3$$
In response to some comments, notice that if we reverse the order, then
$$(f')^{-1}(6)=3$$
Since
$$(f')^{-1}:2x\mapsto x\implies (f')^{-1}(x)=\frac{x}{2}$$
But this is rather obvious, taking e.g $f^{-1}=g$ all this is saying is
$$x=(g^{-1}\circ g)(x)$$
Which is the *definition* of an inverse. What you **can** say in general is as follows: Let $\phi$ be differentiable and invertible. Let $\mathrm{D}$ be the differential operator. Then by definition of inverse
$$\phi^{-1}(\phi(x))=x$$
Taking a derivative,
$$\mathrm{D}\left(s\mapsto \phi^{-1}(\phi(s))\right)(x)=\mathrm{D}(s\mapsto s)(x)$$
Using our chain rule,
$$\mathrm{D}(\phi^{-1})(\phi(x))\phi'(x)=1$$
So
$$\mathrm{D}(\phi^{-1})(\phi(x))=\frac{1}{\phi'(x)}$$
Or, letting $\phi(x)=y\implies x=\phi^{-1}(y)$ and switching back to the prime notation we have
$$(\phi^{-1})'(y)=\frac{1}{\phi'(\phi^{-1}(y))}$$
This formula is nice, but actually rather useless. Basically it says in order to compute the derivative of the inverse at some input, say $x$, one first needs to compute $\phi^{-1}(x)$. But, if we have an easy way of computing $\phi^{-1}$, then in practice we also **already** have an easy way to compute $(\phi^{-1})'$.

---

Key takeaway: Inverse functions are a real pain in the ass.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can come up with a counterexample yourself, as this should almost never hold.

Take $f:(0,\infty)\to (0,\infty$, $f(x)=x^2$. Then $f^{-1}: (0,\infty)\to (0,\infty), x\mapsto \sqrt{x}$.

Now calculate, for example, $f'(2)=4$. But $(f^{-1})'(4)=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{4}}=\frac14$.

Comment: It is different when you reverse the order and look at $(f')^{-1}$. But this is no surprise. As we are just looking at the inverse in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Not so. We can see by a rough graph of its inverse function, here particularly $ \sin , \sin^{-1}$

For a function and its inverse.. due to a reflection about black straight line $x=y$ coordinates are swapped  but the slopes cannot be swapped in same way generally.

$$ \text{ If}  f(u)=v, \text{then} (f^{−1})′(v)=1/f′(u). $$

Due to symmetry w.r.t. line $x=y$ if $ \phi $ is slope for f, then for $f^{-1} $ the slope goes to its complement at corresponding mapped points on the red/blue lines. This is simply because

$$ \frac{dy}{dx} \to \frac{1}{{dx}/{dy}}. $$

$$ \tan(..) \to 1/\tan(..) = \cot(..)= \tan( \pi/2- ...)$$

$$\phi \to \pi/2-\phi $$

[image: Inverse function]